# How can you replace an image in a div to text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-animate, anime.js

I am stuck on how I can write a script in JS so when the user clicks on a image it transitions/ turns into text.

I have a divs in a div as i have to use that for a scrolling animation. So when the user scrolls to the icon in which they want to they can click it and it would  turn into text, like when i click the job icon it shows the jobs listed.

I tried to use ".innerHTML = "Hello World"" though that had failed.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Underscores</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-        
 slotmachine@4.0.0/dist/jquery.slotmachine.min.css"></style>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.2.0/anime.js">        
 </script>
<script     
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">    
 </script>


</head>
<body>


  <div id= "left" class="left">
<img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/underscores.xyz/images/left.png" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="middle" id = "theMiddle" style="width: 400px; height: 300px">
 <div><img     
 src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/underscores.xyz/selectionIcon/About.png"         
 alt="" class="about" id="aboutID"></div>
<div><img 
 src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/underscores.xyz/selectionIcon/job.png" alt=""     
 ></div>
<div><img 
 src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/underscores.xyz/selectionIcon/middle.png" 
 alt=""></div>

  </div>



   <div id= "right" class="right">
    <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/underscores.xyz/images/right.png" 
 alt="">
  </div>


  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-    
 slotmachine@4.0.0/dist/slotmachine.min.js"></script>

  <script src="back.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**JS:**

```
document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
//the key strokes for the up and down keys

// Set up our container
const el = document.querySelector("#theMiddle");
// Create new SlotMachine
const slot = new SlotMachine(el, {});


document.onkeydown = checkKey;
function checkKey(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  //Secret Code: EADWEARD
  anime({
 targets: "div.right",
 translateX: {
  value: 200,
  duration: 500
 }
  });
  anime({
 targets: "div.left",
 translateX: {
  value: -200,
  duration: 500
 }
  });

  if (e.keyCode == "40") {
//this is down
//this will open it up
slot.prev();

  } else if (e.keyCode == "38") {
slot.next();


}
}

//Scroll detection occurs here, without the scrollbar
$("html").on("mousewheel", function(e) {
anime({
targets: "div.right",
translateX: {
  value: 200,
  duration: 500
}
});
anime({
targets: "div.left",
translateX: {
  value: -200,
  duration: 500
}
});
var delta = e.originalEvent.wheelDelta;
if (delta < 0) {
//This is for the scrolling down
// animation opens up the brakets

slot.prev();

}if (delta > 0) {
slot.next();
 }
   });


//this is for detecting clicks  for the divs in the middle div
// 1 = the 2nd image , 2 = the  3rd image
$(".middle div").click(function(){
  if($(this).index() == '1'){

// The change occurs here

console.log("the fucks");
document.getElementById("aboutID").innerHTML = "Hello World";
 }if($(this).index() == '2'){ 

// The change occurs here

  console.log("jobs page");
}
});
```

Comment: You are trying to change the `innerHTML` property of an `img` element(of id `aboutID`). I believe you want to put the text in the `div` instead.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown but that wouldnt replace the image right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`innerHTML` is the property of HTML element, which can be used to get the content within the specified id of the DOM. So, if we want to change image then apply the same on div tag.

Give id to div tag which contains image to be changed.

```
<div id="changetotext"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/underscores.xyz/selectionIcon/About.png" alt="" class="about" id="aboutID"></div>
```

In js change the id to id of div tag.

```
document.getElementById("changetotext").innerHTML = "<p>Hello World</p>";
```

Hope this helps!