# How to Protect click to chat whatsapp button from bots web scraping?

Tags: javascript, php, web-scraping, bots

I'm running a classified website where people post their items and others can contact them by whatsapp to get more details. Today my site got under attack, I see a huge number of link clicks on the whatsapp button in google analytics which could not be by human. I think it's some bot scraping phone numbers from the button link.

```
$phone= $row_posts['phone'];    
// for example $phone="+212612345678"
<div class="contact">
  <a class="btn btn-success" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://wa.me/212$phone?text=TextMessage">
More Details
 </a>   
</div>
```

I'm using this could for the whatsapp button. As you see the phone number is easily showing in the link href. I see some websites like "www.mubawab.ma" which use whatsapp button but you can't see the number from the first time in inspect code. I want to implement something like that so I can protect my users phone numbers from bots web scraping.

Comment: Use images and when the user clicks, you can ajax the number if the click is genuine (captcha for example)

Comment: @mplungjan coud you explain more with an example of code please?

Comment: Show some effort. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51272864/how-can-you-replace-an-image-in-a-div-to-text look for ajax look for captcha

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. Using a reCaptcha style blocker is probably the best option. However, here is a simple one to implement that should stop most bots that aren't a targeted attack.

In PHP, I encode the phone number via **base64_encode**, then I use **atob** in javascript to decode it.

```
<?php
    function obfuscatePhone($phone){
        return base64_encode($phone);
    }
?>

<div class="contact">
  <a class="btn btn-success" data-wakey="<?php echo obfuscatePhone("+212612345678");?>" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="#!">
More Details
 </a>   
</div>

<script>
    const wa = document.querySelectorAll("[data-wakey]");
    wa.forEach((e) => {
        const p = atob(e.dataset.wakey);
        e.href = "https://wa.me/212" + p + "?text=TextMessage";
    });
</script>
```

That code generates this in HTML:

```js
const wa = document.querySelectorAll("[data-wakey]");
wa.forEach((e) => {
  const p = atob(e.dataset.wakey);
  e.href = "https://wa.me/212" + p + "?text=TextMessage";
});
```

```html
<div class="contact">
  <a class="btn btn-success" data-wakey="KzIxMjYxMjM0NTY3OA==" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="#!">
More Details
 </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks That's helps a lot. But if you run this code snippet here in stackoverflow or even when I tried it on my website when you inspect the contact button you got
the data-wakey working but in href still shows the number like this `href="https://wa.me/212612345678?text=TextMessage"`

Comment: I added this to the a tag `onclick="showNumber()"` and put that script in this function and it works and doesn't show the number until button clicked. Is this a good practice that's going to stop bots?

Comment: Nothing will stop dedicated bots, but this might slow them. Some bots will load and execute JS to get such data

Comment: @mplungjan Yes you're right. I applied this code but the attack is still as it was yesterday.

Comment: @kevinroy when you see it in the inspector you are just seeing the generated javascript. However, if the problem still continues then the bot could have copied your source code already and is just running it locally